# Extending class with name matching the namespace

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-4

Consider the following file structure in conjunction with PSR-4 autoloading:

```
.
├── Foo
│   └── Bar.php
└── Foo.php
```

Class `Bar.php` is to extend `Foo.php`. Assuming they reside within a deeply nested namespace already, `Bar.php`'s header will look like:

```
<?php
namespace My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo;
class Bar extends \My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo
{
```

That works perfectly fine. What puzzles me though is whether there is an elegant way **to avoid repeating the string** `My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo`. The potential problem here is that having to repeat it manually can lead to typos and errors that would/could normally be prevented by using the language features efficiently. So I am wondering if there is a way to rewrite the code above in a way like:

```
<?php
namespace My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo;
class Bar extends __NAMESPACE__
{
```

or

```
<?php
namespace My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo;
class Bar extends ..\Foo
{
```

or something similar.

Comment: as far as i know, this is not possible.

Comment: That is what I thought @ins0. Perhaps it could be a feature request.

Answer (score -2):

Thats why you actually have namespaces ;) Namespace does not mean you have to specify "path" to file

Foo.php

```
<?php
namespace \My\Cool\Project;

class Foo {

}
```

Bar.php

```
<?php
namespace \My\Cool\Project;
class Bar extends Foo 
{
}
```

I really dont know how can this leads to error, especially when you are using ide like PHPStorm, when you are using notepad , yes it can leads to error , but its not the case why you should rape PHP because of this.

Comment: Did you read the question? There were no any errors. Also, class `Bar` *is not* in the same namespace as class `Foo`.

Comment: Did you read the answer? - quote of yours question : The potential problem here is that having to repeat it manually can lead to typos and errors that would/could normally be prevented by using the language features efficiently. , And actually Bar IS in same namespace as Foo, look at your code  namespace My\Cool\Project\Module\Foo; inside both files!